# Универсальный обработчик события

Tags: javascript

У меня такая проблема. Есть поле для ввода текста

```
input type="text"
```

и при вводе туда в блоке

```
<h1></h1>
```

inner.HTML'ом сразу же появляется то, что я ввожу в input.

```
onkeyup="document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML=this.value;"
```

Но проблема в том, что если вставить "ПКМ-> Вставить" скопированный текст туда, то в h1 перезаписываться не будет, пока не нажмется какая нибудь кнопка, то же самое с onkeydown.

onchange пока не потеряется фокус и так далее. (ну Вы знаете.)

Подскажите функцию или в какую сторону копать, чтобы не зависимо от того как был вставлен текст, не теряя или наоборот получая фокус поле Input. сразу же перезаписывался h1.

Answer (score 4):

Для ваших целей целесообразно использовать [событие input](http://learn.javascript.ru/events-change#событие-input), но оно не работает ниже ИЕ9.
Текст в инпуте будет изменяться даже при вставке правым кликом мыши

Comment: @mountpoint, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Comment: @Expert, пояснил

Comment: есть ещё событие paste :)

Answer (score 2):

Поможет множественная привязка обработчиков событий в jQuery через [$( ... ).on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('input').on('paste blur keyup change', function(){
    $('h1').html($(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю

```
elem.addEventListener ("paste", handler, false);
```

Comment: с paste все не так уж просто, надо сначала обработчик из потока выкинуть, иначе не узнаете что вставлено. тем более addEventListener нет в IE<9 т.е. смысла использовать так paste нет, вполне хватит input.

Comment: Согласен. Input более подходит.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду копать в этом направлении